# Getting Error When Creating Array Inside Array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I get this error :

```
syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ']'
```

Is there something wrong with my code?

```
class Represent_Graph_Adj_Matrix {
    private $vertices;
    private $adj_matrix = [];

    public function __construct($v) {
        $this->vertices  = $v;
        $this->adj_matrix  = [[$this->vertices + 1],[$this->vertices + 1]];
        var_dump($this->adj_matrix);
    }

    public function makeEdge($to = array(), $from = array(), $edge) {

        try {
            $this->adj_matrix[$to, $from] = $edge; // This is the line of the error
        }
        catch(Exception $e) {
            echo "Vertics does not exists <br>";
        }
    }

    public function getEdge($to, $from) {
        try {
            return $this->adj_matrix[$to][$from];
        }

        catch(Exception $e) {
            echo "Vertics does not exists <br>";
        }

        return -1;
    }

}
```

Can some of you tell me what's wrong that makes my code gets error? 
I have pointed my error line in my code..

Please, I need your help.. 
Thank you..

Comment: $to and $from are arrays. Also assignment syntax is wrong. Try using this `$this->adj_matrix[0][0] = $edge;`

Comment: Thank You.. 
But whole my values are Null..

Comment: As elegant-user said, array assignment syntax is wrong, you can assign like `$this->adj_matrix[$to][$from]`. But again `$to` and `$from` should be integer values rather than an array.

Comment: Thank you for the answer...